# How to draw areas in Google Map?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, dictionary

How to draw zipcode wise or area, city name wise boundaries over google map and from where we can get boundaries co-ordinates?

Sample image is attached. See, I have searched for "Ghaziabad" and google map colored it's complete region.

[image]

Comment: You find someone who provides that info and pay them for access.  But suggesting providers is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this. [Shapes and polygons google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes)

Hope this helps.